# What is a squeeze page for marketing your website?

Tags: marketing

I've been reading a marketing book which suggests building a squeeze page to build an email list.

Does this mean one of those long sales letter type pages with crumby styling?
I'm assuming the styling does not have to be generic, or does it?

Or, if the sales letter is not a squeeze page, what is a squeeze page?

Is there an easy way to build one, and what considerations should be undertaken when building one?

**Update**: I guess a squeeze page can also be referred to as a lead capture page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about E-Mail-Marketing: It simply means a page with a very strong focus on get the visitors to leave their email address.

It's a landing page. But the focus is on getting permission to send mails later on (while other types of landing pages might focus on a download, on a call or something else).

There are lots of plugins out there for Wordpress that focus on variations of the "call to action" to make it easy for you to just focus on your message while providing all the buttons or entry points (...input fields) for the mail.

(There's no need that a squeeze page looks like the typical sixpack testimonial page with lots of yellow background texts. It just happens, sometimes.)

Says an authority: [Squeeze page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_page)

Answer (score 2):

A squeeze page is a single web page with the sole purpose of capturing information for follow-up marketing.

The aim is to collect information such as email addresses, and get permission so you can then start to send a marketing campaign to the potential customer. So you get the email address added to 'your list' and then you need to start marketing to that person to make a sale (or sales) without having them unsubscribe.

Some squeeze pages are pretty tacky, while others are now quite good.
You should have this integrated to an autoresponder pre-set with a marketing campaign too.

There are a huge number of different options.
GetResponse is quite a good one: https://www.getresponse.co.uk/
It was recommended to me.